# Which command line options to use Intel® mpx with clang++?

Tags: linux, c++14, x86-64, clang++, llvm-clang

Most automatic bounds checking tools (like asan or msan or valgrind) works by replacing glibc’s memory allocator with a custom one.

I need to fuzz a Linux application that requires llvm and use a custom allocator incompatible with many memory allocators (even with glibc’s allocator). Software developers even rewrote all third party dependency/subdependency libraries to use their incompatible allocator.
So I can’t use gcc due the llvm requirement, nor I can use address sanitizer.

As far I’m aware, Intel® mpx is the only system able to perform bounds checking without changing the memory allocation method (of course there’s libmpx for perfoming additional checks through wrapping functions but it’s optional).

So how to use Intel mpx with clang++ without wrapping functions to libmpx ? (something normally allowed by gcc command line arguments)

Comment: Of course, I’ve a ᴄᴘᴜ supporting mpx instructions. Maybe mpx isn’t the only bound checker that don’t use a custom alllocator with clang++ meaning an other checker is available ?